Stripe Connect. Account creation
guys! I need your help. I have read all documentation from the stripe, but I still have some concerns about a few things.
My task is to create Stripe Connect for the user from US. We are using Stripe Connect with custom account. But I have some questions.
First of all as described in Stripe Connect docs, my object includes 'company' object and
'individual' object. What is the most prioritized and can I for example create only company object(My code example is below)
Second question, if I have only the individual person have I provide the data for the 'company' object. Have use for the company the separate taxID or cab I use SSN for both?
My code is below:
async createAccount(request: Request, data: CreatePaymentAccountDto) {
    const { birthday } = data;
    const { day, month, year } = this.separateDate(birthday);

    const user = await this.stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'custom',
      country: 'US',
      email: data.email,
      capabilities: {
        card_payments: {
          requested: true,
        },
        transfers: {
          requested: true,
        },
      },
      business_profile: {
        mcc: '7392',
        product_description: data.description,
      },
      external_account: data.bankToken,
      company: {
        tax_id: data.taxID,
        name: `${data.firstName} ${data.lastName} - Consultant`,
      },
      business_type: 'individual',
      individual: {
        dob: {
          day: day,
          month: month + 1,
          year,
        },
        address: {
          city: data.city,
          line1: data.addrLine1,
          postal_code: data.postCode,
          state: data.state,
        },
        email: data.email,
        first_name: data.firstName,
        last_name: data.lastName,
        phone: data.phone,
        ssn_last_4: data.ssn_last_4,
        id_number: data.taxID,
      },
      tos_acceptance: {
        date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
        ip: request.ip,
      },
    });

    return user;
  }


Company and Individual are 2 different types of Accounts. You don't have to fill both. You can use this tool to check which requirements are necessary in each case.

could you please tell me if the person has only SSN, could he use it instead of the tax_id for the 'individual' case
